# How to convert Java code (base64 varint decoding) to PHP?

Tags: java, php, base64, decode

Edit: Solved it, answer below.
In the past week I've been trying to convert some Java code to PHP without any luck.
It's a Hearthstone (card game) deck code decoding code (sounds weird...). The code is a base64 string, which uses a lot of varint arrays.

More information here: https://hearthsim.info/docs/deckstrings/

Only Java and C# code is available. Anyone could give some insights on how to convert java code to php?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't actually a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to get it working, is to use https://wzrd.in/.
In the module, write "deckstring", "latest" version is fine, you get a nice JS file and that's what is needed.